# Shell script into an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, shell

I am having difficulty changing this string into an array. This should be really easy but im pretty new to using ruby and I can't seem to get it, I was trying to use .split.

```
 tcpPorts = %x(sudo netstat -ntpl |awk '{ if(NR > 2) print " "$4" "}' | awk -F: '{print $NF}')
```

Comment: How the array should be? An example of an expected array would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show us the code using `split` that doesn't work? Because I just tried `tcpPorts.split` and it worked perfectly, so I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I you like that all people who know ruby but do not know awk will help you, pleasse add you pronlem description in normal english.

Comment: If you're using Ruby it's really *not* necessary to employ `awk` as well. Do that in Ruby code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `split("\n")` works.

This works correctly on my linux virtual machine:

```
irb(main):002:0> `sudo netstat -ntpl |awk '{ if(NR > 2) print " "$4" "}' | awk -F: '{print $NF}'`.split("\n")
=> ["22 ", "5432 ", "25 ", "38880 ", "6379 ", "111 ", "80 ", "51187 ", "22 ", "5432 ", "25 ", "3306 ", "111 "]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easy at all. But have a look at the standard lib [Shellwords](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html), which has a custom `split` method.